# Scrapy Request on form - url gets truncated

Tags: python, scrapy

## Context - replication of problem

Hello, I have been trying to scrape this webpage here using `Scrapy`: https://www.sec.gov/edgar/search.

As you can see, it is a search page with a form to fill. I would like to scrape a page that is returned when I fill the form this way:

```
'Document word or phrase': 'MSIGX',
'Filing category': 'All annual, quarterly, and current reports',
'Filed data range': 'Last year'
```

When you insert those fields that way, the browser will redirect you to this link https://www.sec.gov/edgar/search/#/q=MSIGX&dateRange=1y&category=form-cat1. In a first instance I thought that those in the link were parameters, but then I realized that there are no question marks in the link.
However, if I execute the code below, the url in the response of the callback function (`parse`) gets truncated to only be https://www.sec.gov/edgar/search and not https://www.sec.gov/edgar/search/#/q=MSIGX&dateRange=1y&category=form-cat1.

```
class Sec(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'sec'

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # unrelevant stuff
        pass

    
    def start_requests(self):
        today = datetime.today()
        year_ago = datetime.today().replace(year=today.year-1)
        url = f'https://www.sec.gov/edgar/search/#/q=MSIGX&dateRange=1y&category=form-cat1'
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, 
                                    headers=get_sec_header(), 
                                    callback=self.parse, 
                                    meta={'s':row["symbol"], 
                                        'dont_redirect': True,
                                        'handle_httpstatus_list': [301, 302]
                                    }, dont_filter=True)
    def parse(self, response):
        print(f'HEEEEEEEELLO {response.url}') # <----- the url is only https://www.sec.gov/edgar/search
```

As a result I cannot scrape the page that I want.

### Debugging

I further debugged this and when I visit https://www.sec.gov/edgar/search/#/q=MSIGX&dateRange=1y&category=form-cat1 on my webbrowser I see the following calls being made:
[image: Devtools - Network tab]
As you can see, there are some subsequent POST calls which I assume load some JS and render the searched items.

**How can I make Scrapy access that final webpage???**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To render the results of those JS functions, you'll need to use a browser emulator like selenium or Splash.

Splash integrates well with scrapy and once you get it up and running you could do something like this:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest


class Sec(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'sec'

    def start_requests(self):
        url = f'https://www.sec.gov/edgar/search/#/q=MSIGX&dateRange=1y&category=form-cat1'
        yield SplashRequest(url, callback = self.parse, endpoint='render.html', args = {'wait': 1})
    
    def parse(self, response):
        with open('response.html', 'w') as outfile: 
            outfile.write(response.text)
        pass
```

Open that `response.html` file to see what the splash engine has done. You can now see the filing entities.

In `settings.py` you will also need to add at least the following:

```
SPLASH_URL = 'http://0.0.0.0:8050' # assuming you are running locally
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
    'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
}
```

For installing splash [you can see this documentation](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html)

And for info about scrapy-splash you can read this  [Github repo](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash)